# sum up results of a recursive function within the same recursive function

Tags: r, recursion

I want to build a data frame like

[image]

In the head I have a value of a number n 
in factorial the factorial(n) which is a recursive function
in sum the sum of the previous values of the factiorials.

I write a recursive function that successfully generate the head and factorial columns but the still struggling with the sum column.

Thanks

Below R code

```
fact <- function(n, x){
  if (n<=1){
    return (n)
  } else {
    n*fact(n-1)
  }
}



recurDf <- function(n, df){
  if (n<=1){
    df <- rbind (df,   data.frame("value" = paste('Value', n) , "factorial" = n, "previous.sum" = 1) )
    return (df)
  } else {
    if(is.null(df)) {
      #df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 0))
      #colnames(df) <- c("value", "factorial", "previous.sum")
      df <- data.frame("value"= 'va', "factorial" =0, "previous.sum" = 0)
    }

    rbind (recurDf(n-1,df), data.frame("value" = paste('Value', n) , "factorial" = fact(n), "previous.sum" = sum(recurDf(n-1,df)$factorial) ))

  }
}

recurDf(4, NULL)
```

Comment: Check out the function `cumsum` for creating the `sum` column e.g. `cumsum(c(1,2,6,24))`. You can do this outside of your first column in one line, not in the loop

Comment: Rather than `if (is.null(df))`, use `if (missing(df))`. Then you can call `recurDF(4)` instead of explicitly passing the `NULL` in.

Comment: Thank you @JonnyPhelps for your helpful tips, for cumsum ,I cannot use it, as my function is more complex than the given example and need to run the sum in the same recusive function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following returns the factor of n in its first component and the cumulative sum of all factorials to n in its second argument.

```
fact2 <- function(n) {
  if (n <= 1) c(1,1)
  else {
    prev <- Recall(n-1)
    n * prev[1] + c(0, prev[2])
  }
}

fact2(1)
## [1] 1 1
fact2(2)
## [1] 2 3
fact2(3)
## [1] 6 9
fact2(4)
## [1] 24 33

cbind(1:4, t(sapply(1:4, fact2)))
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    1    1    1
## [2,]    2    2    3
## [3,]    3    6    9
## [4,]    4   24   33
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you need to do this recursively?

There are much simpler ways to get to your answer.

```
recurDf <- function(n){
  df <- data.frame("value" = c(paste('Value',1:n)) , "factorial" = c(1:n)) 
  df$factorial <- factorial(df$factorial)
  df$previous.sum <- cumsum(df$factorial)
  return (df)
}

recurDf(4)
```

This returns

```
    value     factorial   previous.sum
 1 Value 1         1            1
 2 Value 2         2            3
 3 Value 3         6            9
 4 Value 4        24           33
```

Comment: thank  you @Chris for your proposal, but I need recursive function for my case

Comment: @moufkir In that case, you can just add `fact(n)` to the `previous.sum` portion of your `rbind`. `"previous.sum" = sum(recurDf(n-1,df)$factorial) + fact(n)`